# How can I dump a static executable with Common Lisp?

Tags: linux, common-lisp, static-linking, sbcl

I am using SBCL, although I have seen other implementations have similar functionality. I can dump an executable that does not require the Lisp implementation to be installed, but does rely on the standard C library. How can I make the dumped image be statically linked (i.e. have no dependencies whatsoever)?

When I am done using an image, I can call

```
(save-lisp-and-die "image-name" :executable t)
```

this will leave a file called `image-name` in my directory that I can then call with `./image-name`. I will be dropped into a repl and everything I had done before saving-lisp-an-dying will still be there. My problem is that when I move this file to another machine, I cannot run it. Either I get the 'file not found' error, or I am told that the wrong version of GLIBC is installed. Running `file` on the image reveals it was dynamically linked. Is there a way to dump a statically linked image that I can just copy to any machine with a Linux kernel?

Comment: Possibly useful reading: [Static Executables with SBCL](https://www.timmons.dev/posts/static-executables-with-sbcl.html), [Static Executables with SBCL v2](https://www.timmons.dev/posts/static-executables-with-sbcl-v2.html)

Comment: For the GLIBC issue, a workaround would be to build your binary with an old enough version, that should be compatible with newer ones. You could do it on a CI system, using e.g. Debian 8 or 9 as a base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a dynamically linked executable with

```
(save-lisp-and-die "image-name" :executable t)
```

Then use one of the [differents ways to generate a statically linked executable from a dynamically linked executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537479/is-there-any-open-source-way-to-make-a-static-from-a-dynamic-executable-with-no).

I've tried with [packelf.sh](https://github.com/oufm/packelf/blob/master/packelf.sh), it works great !

Comment: This definitely picks my curiosity. Do you know if it's doing more than Deploy? Does it create a "true" statically linked executable, does it handle the wrong GLIBC version issue? Thanks!

Comment: packelf.sh packs everything in a tar file then it makes it an executable. You may try to unpack it, or try other proposed alternatives like mkblob or statifier.

Comment: Can you show how you invoke Packelf for a CL binary?

Answer (score 1):

A good complementary tool to `save-lisp-and-die` is [Deploy](https://github.com/Shinmera/deploy).

What kind of "file not found" message did you have? Deploy helps to ship foreign libraries dependencies alongside your binary, such as libssl.so or libmagic.so, so they don't need to be that exact version on the target OS, or there at all.

To use it, you tweak your .asd declaration and use:

```lisp
:defsystem-depends-on (:deploy)  ;; (ql:quickload "deploy") before
:build-operation "deploy-op"     ;; instead of "program-op"
:build-pathname "my-application-name"  ;; doesn't change
:entry-point "my-package:my-start-function"  ;; doesn't change
```

and you build your binary with `(asdf:make :my-app)` like usual.

Deploy creates a `bin/` directory with your binary and the dependencies. This is what you have to ship now.

It should be possible to package everything in one executable archive, but I didn't get to it yet.

---

More info: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/scripting.html#with-deploy---ship-foreign-libraries-dependencies

We actually don't mess with libssl, so we tell Deploy to ignore it:

```lisp
#+linux (deploy:define-library cl+ssl::libssl :dont-deploy T)
#+linux (deploy:define-library cl+ssl::libcrypto :dont-deploy T)
```

Use `(push :deploy-console *features*)` to silence Deploy at start-up.